# create the symlink failed in yocto project

Tags: cmake, yocto

Error log, **do_package_qa**:

```
QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so
```

source code, **CMakeList.txt**:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${TARGETNAME} PROPERTIES VERSION 1.0 SOVERSION 1)
```

Whether I need to add some parameter like `-dev` or `-dbg`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either manually install those *.so files and symlinks to them in `do_install()` for `PACKAGE_${PN}-dev`, or add the following to the recipe:

```
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
SOLIBS = ".so"
```

Comment: You are right @Oleksandr, I tried your solution. But I also add the `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so" ` in the bb file, because there are  too many language need to change, so I modify the bb file of the module in yocto.